# UnboundExecutionError in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Note**:  *This is in SQLAlchemy 0.5.7.  It appears that this is not possible as the "lazy" does not work on one-to-one mapping.  If it does and I got it wrong, please post your answer.*

---

I have the following method, which should return all instances of any class those parent is `Parent`.  Note that a class `Child` has an attribute called `fubar` which is another class.  I have mapped those correctly elsewhere.

```
def get_all(self):
    session = self.__Session()
    lst = session.query(Parent).with_polymorphic('*').all()
    #print lst # <-- this commented back in and it all works.
    session.expunge_all()
    session.close()
    return lst
```

I can then do things like `for item in get_all(): [...]` and all that. In the mapping for `child`, I have `lazy-False` so I would have assumed that it would be loaded fine. However, if I leave the print line commented in, all I get is this exception:

```
UnboundExecutionError: Parent instance <Child at 0xa1bca4c> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'fubar' cannot proceed
```

The thing I do not understand is this: when the print line is there, the objects are indeed loaded fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Thanks to @van, I think the `fubar` objects are indeed loaded in a lazy manner.  I have the following in the mapping:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Child, tb_child, inherits=Parent, 
    polymorphic_identity='Child', properties={'fubar':
        sqlalchemy.orm.relation(Child,
                lazy=False,
                uselist=False, 
                cascade="all, delete-orphan")
            }
        )
```

The code for the parent is this:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Parent,
        tb_parent, 
        polymorphic_on=tb_parent.c.type, 
        polymorphic_identity='Parent')
```

What is wrong with this?...

Alternatively, how can I force `query()` to load everything in a non-lazy way?

Comment: Does the `repr` of your `Parent` print also a `Child`? so that it is loaded because of the very `print`? Enable `echo=True` and see if `Child` is lazy-loaded while `print`-ing.

Comment: @van: Yes, the repr of the `Parent` does indeed called the `repr` of the child.  Yes, it looks like the `fubar` object is lazy loaded.  Dammit!  Question updated.  Thank you.

Comment: But in your edit I do not see any "fubar" relationship defined, only "ref"... ?

Comment: @van: Yes, my mistake.  Fixed now.

Comment: can you please reply to my questions in the answer thread as well?

Comment: @van: done.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @see my *edit-1* with usage of `eager_load` to load it in non-lazy way. But what I find really strange is that for both `Parent` and `Child` you use the same `polimorphic_identity='Parent'`. Should not the one for `Child` objects be `Child`? If yes and you have already stored some `Child` objects in the DB, you might need to update the `type` column values.

Comment: @van: Sorry, the `polimorphic_identity='Parent'` should have been 'Child' for the child.  I am testing this on an in memory sqlite database which is re-created every time I run the (test) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Relationship API documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#relationships-api) (scroll down to the explanation of `lazy` parameter):

```
lazy=’select’ – specifies how the related items should be loaded. Default value is select. Values include:
    ...
    noload - no loading should occur at any time. This is to support “write-only” attributes, or attributes which are populated in some manner specific to the application.
    ...
    True - a synonym for ‘select’
    False - a synonyn for ‘joined’
    None - a synonym for ‘noload’
```

So by setting `lazy=None` you are actually not configuring relationship to be eager-loaded, but getting almost the opposite result. You should use one of: `immediate, joined or subquery` instead.

**edit-1**: in light of the fact that SA-0.5 is used: I am not sure why the relationship is not eagerly loaded, but you might try to explicitely specify it in a query and see if it works:

```
lst = (session.query(Parent).with_polymorphic('*').
    options(eagerload('fubar')).all()) # confused if it is "fubar" or "ref"
```

Comment: Any chance of a pointer to version 0.5?  Yes, I am working on a legacy system that only has that installed on it.  I *could* update but it would be a hard sell.  Thanks.  All I could find were: `lazy=(True|False|None|’dynamic’)` which don't really help.

Comment: On a side note, I am using `lazy=False` as well as version 0.5 which may make a difference.

Comment: Indeed, the SA version matters here. Could you provide the mapping code for the Parent as well? I find a bit confusing that polymorphic_identity for a Child is 'Parent'... Also, what is the nature of this relation "ref"? cardinality? I am wondering if "lazy" did not work properly for "?-to-1" relations in 0.5.

Comment: I am wondering if "lazy" did not work properly for "?-to-1" relations in 0.5 as well since your edit-1 still does not do it -- and it should.  I shall try using 0.7 and see.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: ... And the price go to "lazy does not work with one-to-one relations in 0.5. At least I cannot make it work.  Looks like I will have to update to 0.7.  Ah well, not a bad thing to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, I meant one-to-one... I really should stop trying to do ten things at once, it does not work for me.   I suspect that the many-to-one would not work either but have not tested it.  I have a working solution with 0.7.3 and am not keen to investigate for much longer as I am approaching a deadline for this.  Damn you deadlines! ^_~

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  It was really useful.